# Searching for terms within a query text parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table in SQL Server (I'm using 2008 R2):

```
Sites ( SiteId, Name )
```

Say I have the following data:

```
-----------------------------------------
- SiteId - Name                         -
-----------------------------------------
-      1 - Foo Bar Baz                  -
-      2 - Qux Tar                      -
-      3 - Contoso                      -
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to allow a user to search for "`baz foo`" and it returning row 1. I want SQL Server to break an input string up and return only rows where the column value matches all of the criteria.

Logically, this would be something like this:

```
function Search(query) {
    query = query.Split(" ");
    sql = "SELECT ..."
    foreach(term in query) {
        sql += "WHERE Name LIKE " + term + " AND ";
    }
    executeSql( sql );
}
```

I understand that T-SQL makes working with arrays very difficult, but surely there must be some built-in construct that performs tokenization/term-matching?

Comment: `T-SQL makes working with arrays very difficult` but it works with tables and since SQL Server 2008 you can pass table from client.

Comment: My client is a VBScript using ADO. That ups the difficulty :)

Comment: Your sql statement is dynamic, too or you just want to split a string and look for each value existance?

Comment: I'm hoping to do it without having to resort to Dynamic-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to find any value in a database, look here : http://plixa.nl/find-any-value-in-a-database/ It includes a script that you can use!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function to build your SELECT statement

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FINDWORDS](@SEARCHTERMS VARCHAR(150), @TABLE VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @CURRENTCOUNT AS INT
DECLARE @MAXCOUNT AS INT
DECLARE @SEARCHSTATEMENT AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @CURRENTITEM AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @WORDS TABLE (ROWNUMBER INT, ITEMS VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @WORDS(ROWNUMBER, ITEMS)
SELECT ROWNUMBER = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY items), items
FROM dbo.splitfn(@SEARCHTERMS, ' ')

SET @CURRENTCOUNT = 1
SET @MAXCOUNT = (SELECT MAX(ROWNUMBER) FROM @WORDS)
SET @SEARCHSTATEMENT = 'SELECT SiteId, Name 
                        INTO #MYTABLE
                        FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE Name LIKE ''%' 

WHILE(@CURRENTCOUNT <= @MAXCOUNT)
    BEGIN
        IF @CURRENTCOUNT > 1
            BEGIN
                SET @SEARCHSTATEMENT = @SEARCHSTATEMENT + ' AND NAME LIKE ''%'
            END
        SET @CURRENTITEM = (SELECT items 
                            FROM @WORDS 
                            WHERE ROWNUMBER = @CURRENTCOUNT)
        SET @SEARCHSTATEMENT = @SEARCHSTATEMENT + @CURRENTITEM + '%'''
        SET @CURRENTCOUNT = @CURRENTCOUNT + 1
    END

RETURN @SEARCHSTATEMENT

END
```

Then create a procedure to call the SELECT statement (since we can't execute a SQL string from within a function)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FINDWORDS2] @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(200)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @STRING AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @STRING = DBO.FINDWORDS(@SEARCHSTRING, 'SITES') + ' SELECT * FROM #MYTABLE'

EXEC(@STRING)

END
```

You're now ready to search for a particular string using the procedure

```
EXEC FINDWORDS2 @SEARCHSTRING = 'baz foo'
```